# Where do I put client variables to access fitbit public data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oauth-2.0, fitbit

I am following this tutorial: https://roboticape.com/2014/01/13/first-steps-into-the-quantified-self-getting-to-know-the-fitbit-api/

Step 5 says:
With the client variables we can access public data on Fitbit.

```
import fitbit
import ConfigParser

#Load Settings
parser = ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser()
parser.read('config.ini')
consumer_key = parser.get('Login Parameters', 'C_KEY')
consumer_secret = parser.get('Login Parameters', 'C_SECRET')

#Setup an unauthorised client (e.g. with no user)
unauth_client = fitbit.Fitbit(consumer_key, consumer_secret)

#Get data for a user
user_params = unauth_client.user_profile_get(user_id='1ABCDE')
```

I am not sure where to put this code.

This is the github repo it tells you to pull from: https://github.com/orcasgit/python-fitbit

I created a new file in the main directory but then I get an error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'" (even though I have done pip install ConfigParser)

Can anyone help or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Just a hunch, are you using PyCharm by any chance?

Comment: Also, regarding the file, you register your app as in Step 2 and receive a Key and Secret. Put that in a file called `config.ini` as shown in Step 4. Then the ConfigParser package will read those values

Comment: @razdi no I'm using VScode. I have registered my app and created that config.ini file in the main directory, and put my Key and Secret in that file. The issue I have is where do I then create the file for that code above to call the key and secret? I have assumed it needs to be in a new py file in the main directory but that's when I get this error. Thanks for your help!!